# Android padding problem

Tags: android, view, border, padding, margin

:) I'm having the following problem: I have a view and i want to add borders to it. What I'm currently trying to do is to set padding to the view (padding from all the sides) and set background color to it which will fill the padding. The thing is that it seems to me that it's possible to set padding either only from top and left or from bottom and right but not from all of them together. I.e if i write

```
view.setPadding(border,border,border,border)
```

this will set padding only from top and left. In order to set padding from bottom and right I have to write:

```
view.setPadding(-border,-border,0,0)
```

which won't leave left and top padding and so on. If I try to use margin it moves the whole block(the view + the padding area), but not only the view, so this doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas on how to do it without having to use a wrapping layout? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly happens when you use the first example?

The four `int` parameters for `setPadding()` are for left, top, right, and bottom, respectively. So, calling `setPadding(4, 5, 6, 7)` should give you 4 pixels of space for the left edge, 5 for the top, 6 for the right, and 7 for the bottom. What result are you getting when you do this? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: When i write this it only sets padding from top and left. I can't give a screenshot as I don't have the source code on the computer I'm currently working on, but it properly sets the top and left border and there's no bottom and right border.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, on Amplify's note, what type of View is it?

Comment: it's a relative layout that may contain not only images.

Comment: Try adding `android:clipToPadding="true"` to the XML layout, or if it's instantiated in code, call `setClipToPadding(true)` on the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2):

What is the content of your view? If it's an image or something similar, perhaps it's not being centered or scaled properly. Try calling `setGravity(CENTER);`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try ASAP. Basically the view is a RelativeLayout but it's content may vary - images/slideshows/etc.

Comment: @iLate will the RelativeLayout always be the same size or will it "wrap content"? If it doesn't change size, just set the background to a solid, distinct color until you get the spacing just right. That way it's easier to see where it is, exactly.